# reading a whole line of strings and separated them by whitespace

Tags: c++

I need help regarding this problem. I try to write a program which allows the user to enter a number of input strings and the strings themselves. The problem lies when I try to pull out each string separately.

Note: The user just has to type all the strings in one shot and separate them by white spaces. Once the user hits enter, the program will need to separate them by white space.

For example:
Input:
2
hack hack
Output:
String 0: hack
String 1: hack
Unique string: 1

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define SIZE 10000
#define LENGTH 100

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int a;                  // number of strings
    string str[SIZE];       // array of strings
    int count =0; 
    int unique_count = 0;


    // read the inputs
    cin >> a ;

    if (a>=1 && a<=SIZE)
    {
        while(count<a)
        {
            getline(cin, str[count]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i< count ; i++)
    {
        if(str[i].compare(str[i+1])==0)
            unique_count++;
        cout << "String " << i << " : " << str[i] << endl;
    }

    // return the output
    cout << "Unique string count: " <<  unique_count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the strings are separated by spaces you want to use operator <<, not getline. In either case you need to chack that the input operation actually worked. And I would strongly suggest using line-based records, std::vector and operator== for strings.

Comment: @NeilButterworth "`operator <<`" i suppose you meant `operator>>` .. but it's quite tricky to do that "The user just has to type all the strings in one shot and separate them by white spaces." requirement.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::istream& eatws(std::istream &is)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = is.peek()) != EOF && ch != '\n' && 
           std::isspace(static_cast<char unsigned>(ch)))
        is.get();
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    char ch;
    std::string word;
    std::size_t unique_words = 0;
    while ((std::cin >> eatws >> std::noskipws >> ch) && ch != '\n' &&
           std::cin.putback(ch) && (std::cin >> word >> eatws)) {

        if (std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), word) == words.end())
            ++unique_words;
        words.push_back(word);

        if (std::cin.peek() == '\n')
            break;
    }

    for (std::size_t i{}; i < words.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "String " << i << ": " << words[i] << '\n';

    std::cout << "Unique string count: " << unique_words << '\n';
}
```